# RXTX Java librairie bug

Tags: java, arduino, rxtx

i am not quite good in english, so i will try to be clear for you. 
I am currently working on a multi-program project. 
I have written an Arduino Control Program, which allow me to manage a sensor network through commands. For example, I can add sensors by typing the command "add   " etc ...

I have also write a Java API for micro controller for sensor data collection (it works with every type of micro controllers), which is able to send command file to my micro controller, to get back the received data and store them into a file in a format of my choice (JSON, XML, PostScript, bytecode ...) and can also send it under http header form to an IP address ...

I have the following problem :

When I send a command from my Java program to my micro controller, the Java program is sometimes not able to receive the command execution response, what makes it crash :

```
Stable Library
=========================================
Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7
Received line : I: Tab cleared.
Received line : I: Setup terminated
|MicroController.java->messageReceived|: recieved response : I: Setup terminated
Send : add t1 2 3
Received line : I:|Main loop| command received :add t1 2 3
Received line : I:|Main loop| command add t1 2 3 in execution ...
Received line : I:|Main loop| command add t1 2 3 executed.
Received line : I:|Main loop| return code 0 sent.
```

As you can see, the micro controller sent the return code "0", but the Java didn't received it.

I have written my own send() and receive() method :

```
/**
 * Send message.
 * 
 * @param str String to send.
 * 
 * @throws IOException IO error.
 * @throws InterruptedException 
 */
public void sendMessage(String str)
throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
   System.out.println("Send : " + str);

   // Send the command.
   output.write(str.getBytes());
   output.flush();
}

/**
 * Handle input event on the serial port.
 * 
 * @param oEvent Event receives.
 */
private synchronized void processReceivedEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent)
{
   if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
   {
      try
      {
         // Wait input to be ready (mandatory, exception o/w).
         while (!input.ready())
         {
            Thread.sleep(1);
         }
         String inputLine = input.readLine();
         System.out.println("Received line : " + inputLine);

         // Notify listener.
         if ((listener != null) && (inputLine != null))
            listener.messageReceived(inputLine);
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         if (port != null)
            e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Maybe I have some synchronized error, which make a serial reading error, but I'm curious to know if there is some kind of conflict between my send and receive method with the serial librairie method ...

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "the micro controller sent the return code "0", but the Java didn't received it", your are printing it from the Java program.